# How to change default number of max process per user in linux

Tags: linux, process, terminal

I have faced a problem with the changing the default number of processes for user in linux. I have tried to edit **/etc/security/limits.conf** file with adding the following line.

```
malintha hard nproc 10000
```

After I saving it I tried following command on terminal

```
ulimit -u
```

and it give the previous value (1024) , But not the updated value. How can I fix this permanently ?

this is my limits.conf file

Comment: Did you logout and relogin?

Comment: Well, `ulimit` is shell specific OTOH, changing /etc/security/limits.conf is related to PAM, see `man pam` for details. Changing /etc/security/limits.conf shouldn't effect ulimit.

Comment: This article answers your question: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-limiting-user-process.html

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you specify "hard" in

malintha hard nproc 10000

hard is the "max" limit, and soft is the default.  So you can leave it as hard and then use `ulimit -u 1000` and processes after that point, for that bash shell, will have the increased limit, or use soft, then it will be the default for all processes started by your user [remember to logout and re-login with each change].

For those looking to try and figure out why they are limited to [for instance] 1024 max theads for a given user, also note that it reads the /etc/security/limits.conf file and other /etc/security/limits.d/* files.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the file requires a server reboot, you can use a simpler way:

```
chuser nofiles=10000 malintha
```

disconnect from you console and reconnect again using the username `malintha`. Use `ulimit -n`  and the output should now be `10000`.